# How to make a TP-LINK TL-WN321G wireless card work? (Sugar on a Stick, Fedora 23)

Tags: fedora, wifi, drivers

I am trying to connect to the WiFi using my `TP-LINK TL-WN321G wireless card`.

After some research on the Internet I've found out that it might not be the case of a missing driver, since there is a file `rt73.bin` in the `/lib/firmware` directory.

According to [this website](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/tp-link-tl-wn321g-linux-driver-914015/) it might be the case of 2 missing packages:  `wireless-tools` and `rt71w-firmware`.

Simultaneously, I've learnt that my problem might go away if I download `linux-firmware-nonfree` package. I wasn't lucky enough however to find any instructions on how to download it and install it offline.

The `build-essential` package is showing up from time to time as well in the threads about this problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/465478/tp-link-tl-wn321g-driver-lubuntu-14-04-install.
Note that I've got nor `wlan0` neither `ipconfig` programs installed.

How can I make my wifi card work?

Here are some additional links I've found during my journey across the Internet:

- [Guy doesn't know how to connect to Wifi on Sugar. (Btw, `sudo yum upgrade` is said to break Sugar).](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/48518/install-wireless-driver-from-command-line-for-sugar-desktop/)

Extra notes:

- The system is Sugar on a Stick (Fedora 23) (Sugar 0.106) i686 running as a LiveCD.